# mosquitto - bridging options for remote client identifier

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, bridge

From [mosquitto.conf](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html), the following options (among many others) exist for bridging.

- `connection` *name*

> This variable marks the start of a new bridge connection. It is also
>   used to give the bridge a name which is used as the client id on the
>   remote broker.

- `remote_clientid` *id*

> Set the client id for this bridge connection. If not defined, this
>   defaults to 'name.hostname', where name is the connection name and
>   hostname is the hostname of this computer.

If **both** the configuration options are specified *and* are different, then which ID applies to the remote broker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the `connection` line is a required field to start a bridge config `remote_clientid` will always override, this should be clear from the description of the `remote_clientid`.

It states that the default will be

> 'name.hostname'

Where `name` is the argument given in the `connection` line.

(Also this literally takes 2 mins to test on the command line by starting 2 brokers)